# Search widget in Experience Builder does not allow you to enter the region or country as the Web AppBuilder allowed you

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, geocoding, arcgis-experience-builder, geocoding-service

Experience Builder does not allow me to put ES as region in the search widget in Experience Builder or I cannot locate and the Esri Web AppBuilder allowed me to do this and it is important because the search is based on ArcGIS. World Geocoding Service and when I put ES I filter it only for Spain, I also don't see the possibility of it only searching in the map extension as if the Web App builder did. Do you have information about it? Or if it is possible to enable the search by map extension in the Experience builder and place ES so that it only searches in Spain?

Added to that is that if I go to AGOL it doesn't solve it either, but it does allow me to make a Locator (view) which in this case has been created for an area of Tenerife based on ArcGIS World Geocoding Service, putting it within a specific area. area but unlike other layers or services it does not allow me or I do not know how to download it with my credentials to my ArcGIS Enterprise 11.1 to be able to use it on the Server of said project.

The truth is that I don't understand how something as useful as just searching from the map extension or filtering by ES and that works so well in the Web AppBuilder and is so simple has become so complicated in something that is supposed to be new. It will help improve and of course the other thing would be to create a locator for that area from a professional based on ArcGIS World Geocoding Service, but that means looking at what the utilities of our servers are like.

Can someone explain to me how to download my AGOL locator (view) to my ArcGIS Enterprise with my credentials to use it in the Experience Builder with the Search Widget so I don't have to create an ArcGIS Pro locator that would also have to be created from ArcGIS World . . Geocoding Service to then publish it to my server, although if there was no other way to pass my locator (view) from AGOL, then I would have to go with that solution and I don't see anywhere how to create the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service locator in Pro and with the ability to place it within a specific area as allowed by AGOL

Answer (score 0):

> Experience Builder does not allow me to put ES as region in the search widget in Experience Builder

If I am understanding correctly, you can search like "ES: Madrid" or "US: Madrid" and it filters results to the country prior to the ":".

[image: Searching "US: Madrid"]

[image: Searching "ES: Madrid"]

> I also don't see the possibility of it only searching in the map
> extension

AFAIK, you are correct; there is no current configuration to only search within the MapView's extent. Your described alternative approach (creation of a Locator for a specific area only) seems appropriate in that absence.

> Can someone explain to me

Sorry, I'm not experienced in this.